# Why must the directional derivative $au_x + bu_y$ always be zero?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I am currently studying the textbook *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction*, second edition, by Walter A. Strauss. Chapter **1.2 First-Order Linear Equations** says the following:

> Let us solve
>
> $$au_x + bu_y = 0,$$
>
> where $a$ and $b$ are constants not both zero.
>
> **Geometric Method** The quantity $au_x + bu_y$ is the directional derivative of $u$ in the direction of the vector $\mathbf{V} = (a, b) = a \mathbf{i} + b \mathbf{j}$. It must always be zero. This means that $u(x, y)$ must be constant in the direction of $\mathbf{V}$.

Why must it always be zero?

I would appreciate it if someone would please take the time to clarify this.

---

### EDIT:

The authors go on to say the following:

> **Coordinate Method** Chang variables (or "make a change of coordinates"; Figure 2) to
>
> $$x^\prime = ax + by \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ y^\prime = bx - ay. \tag{3}$$
>
> Replace all $x$ and $y$ derivatives by $x^\prime$ and $y^\prime$ derivatives. by the chain rule,
>
> $$u_x = \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x^\prime}} \dfrac{\partial{x^\prime}}{\partial{x}} + \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y^\prime}} \dfrac{\partial{y^\prime}}{\partial{x}} = au_{x^\prime} + bu_{y^\prime}$$
>
> $$u_y = \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} = \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y^\prime}} \dfrac{\partial{y^\prime}}{\partial{y}} + \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x^\prime}} \dfrac{\partial{x^\prime}}{\partial{y}} = bu_{x^\prime} - au_{y^\prime}.$$
>
> Hence $au_x + bu_y = a(au_{x^\prime} + bu_{y^\prime}) + b(bu_{x^\prime} - au_{y^\prime}) = (a^2 + b^2)u_{x^\prime}$. So, since $a^2 + b^2 \not= 0$, the equation takes the form $u_{x^\prime} = 0$ in the new (primed) variables. Thus the solution is $u = f(y^\prime) = f(bx - ay)$, with $f$ an arbitrary function of *one* variable.

Again, it is not clear here why $a^2 + b^2 \not= 0$ implies that the equation takes the form $u_{x^\prime} = 0$ in the new (primed) variables.

Comment: doesn't it follow by the DE?

Comment: @goblinb what is DE?

Comment: the differential equation

Comment: I actually read that passage yesterday and took it to mean that the DE states that the directional derivative must be $0$, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: @goblinb Well, I'm not sure that that is why the directional derivative must be zero. It seems to me that they're saying that there is a more fundamental reason, related to the concept of directional derivative.

Comment: It could be poorly worded, but yes, I see what you mean

Comment: @goblinb You might be right. Nitin Uniyal's answer seems to suggest that it was just set to zero, rather than it being zero due to some fundamental reason related to the directional derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$au_x + bu_y = 0\\
\implies \left (\hat i\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\hat j\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right ) \cdot (a\hat i+b\hat j)=0\\
\implies (\vec{\nabla u}) \cdot (a\hat i+b\hat j)=0$

Thus the directional derivative  $(\vec{\nabla u})$ in the direction of vector $\vec V=(a,b)$ is zero.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question; but, nonetheless, you might have inadvertently answered it anyway. So it seems to me that what you're saying is that it equals zero *by design* (that is, we have just set it to zero), rather than by some fundamental necessity/fact relating to the directional derivative? This is what I was confused about.

Comment: Directional derivative can be any nonzero real number unless $u(x,y)$ is constant in direction of vector $V$.

Answer (score 1):

The P.D.E is satisfied by some $u$ if

$\vec{\nabla} u$ is always perpendicular to  $a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}$.

This means,

$\vec{\nabla}u=F(x,y)(-b\hat{i}+a\hat{j})$, for some scaler function $F(x,y)$.

$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-bF(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=aF(x,y)$.....(1)

> If $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y\partial x}$,
>
> then $F(x,y)$ is itself solution of the given differential equation.

Such solutions are $u(x,y)=-bx+ay$; $u(x,y)=e^{-bx+ay}$

So, from one solution you get another and this continues.

For example if we use, $F(x,y)=-bx+ay$, then we get $u(x,y)=\frac{b^2x^2}{2}-abxy+\frac{a^2x^2}{2}$.

We get another $u(x,y)$, from here. If the infinite solution set is $\mathcal T$. Then it follows some properties....

For any $u ,v \in \mathcal T$, then

1) $cu+dv \in \mathcal T,  (c,d) \in \mathbb R^2$.

2) And most interestingly $u(x,y)v(x,y) \in \mathcal T$.

[ As$(a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}).\vec{\nabla}uv \\ =(a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}).(v\vec{\nabla}u+u\vec{\nabla}v)$. ]

Hence, $\mathcal T$ is an infinite set which is closed under multiplication and addition.

Comment: But how does this tell me why it must always be equal to $0$?

Comment: Its not always zero. Use the examples.